# Integrable sequence of functions $f_n$ that converges uniformly implies that $f$ is integrable and integrals are the same

Tags: measure-theory, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_n)$ be an integrable sequence of functions on $\Omega$ that converges uniformly $f_n \rightarrow f$.
Show that if $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$ then (1) $f$ is integrable and (2) $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f_n d \mu=\int f d \mu$.

So by definition $f_n$ converges uniformly if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ so that for all $n \geq N$:

$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

In other proofs that I have found is says that it is also less than or equal to $\epsilon/\mu(\Omega)$ which I don't quite understand?

To show (1) I need to show that $\int_{\Omega}|f| d \mu <\infty$ and for (2) $|\int f_n d \mu-\int f d \mu| \rightarrow0.$

I guess for (1) I somehow need to prove that the integral is less than the integral of $|f_n|$ which is finite by definition. I'm not sure how to prove (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\mu (\Omega) < \infty$ the constant function $1_{\Omega}$ on $\Omega$ is integrable ($\int 1_{\Omega}d\mu = \mu(\Omega)$) and thereby also $f_n + \epsilon$ and $f_n-\epsilon$ by linearity of the integral. As the $f_n$ converge uniformly, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ $|f_n-f|<\epsilon$ and so $f_n-\epsilon<f<f_n+\epsilon$, so $f$ is bounded by an integrable function and therefor integrable (This follows from the dominance convergence theorem and the fact that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, so every integrable function is absolutely integrable).

But now for the integral we get by monotony that:

$\int f_nd\mu - \epsilon*\mu(\Omega) =\int (f_n-\epsilon) d\mu < \int fd\mu<\int (f_n+\epsilon) d\mu<\int f_nd\mu + \epsilon*\mu(\Omega)$ for $n>n_0$

As $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary this gives for all $\delta>0$ an $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ $|\int(f_n-f)d\mu|<\delta$ if we choose $\epsilon=\delta/\mu(\Omega)$, so the integral converges.

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate more on why $1_\Omega$ and $f_n + \epsilon$ are integrable? I also don't understand why $\int f_nd\mu - \epsilon*\mu(\Omega) =\int (f_n-\epsilon) d\mu$?

Comment: Any scaling of integrable functions are integrable and (finite) sums of integrable functions as well, this is the linearity of the integral

Comment: So $\epsilon \mu(\Omega) = \int \epsilon d\mu$?

Comment: Yes and as you can see this is only well defined for $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$